# How can I scrape historical data from investing.com using Python?

Tags: python, request

I would like to get historical IRS data, say, from 01/01/2020 til from investing.com.

With the simple code as below :

```
dfs = []
urls =['https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/eur-2-years-irs-interest-rate-swap-historical-data', 'https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/eur-10-years-irs-interest-rate-swap-historical-data']
for url in urls:
    
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df = pd.read_html(html)
    dfs.append(df)
```

I got only the displayed data. The question is similar as [scrapin historical data from investing.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866926/scrapin-historical-data-from-investing-com).

The answer works perfectly. However, I don't understand quite well how it works. Could someone give some explainations and how should I adapt the code to my problem ?

Thanks a lot !!