# Scrape economic data from investing.com using Power Query

Tags: excel, web-scraping, powerquery, economics

I want to scrape the data from the economic calendar using PQ on Excel.

I went on Data>From Web and I used this URL "https://it.investing.com/economic-calendar/exports-1762".

However, I'm able to extract the data from the table that is diplayed on the website, but I'd like to retrieve the data from 2020 up to the last data. Is there any way to do it with Power Query?

I also tried using this url: "https://it.investing.com/economic-calendar/exports-1762?date_from=2010-01-01&date_to=2023-01-01" but it's not working.
I could try by manually extend the table from investing.com, but I'd like to extraact several macro-variable, so would be so much time consuming.

Comment: Check out the many similar questions on here, this is but one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73866926/4961700

Comment: Thanks, but they're using Python. I already searched but I couldn't find anything for PQ

Comment: You can answer even in a more polite way, rather than being aggressive. Anyway, thank you.