# Scraping historical data from investing.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape historical data of financial reports. However, I figured out how to scrape the table shown by investing.com, but If I want older data, I can't, since investing has a "Show more" and I don't know how to fix this problem.

I want to extract from all the reports so for the sake of the example if someone can help me scrape from this address https://it.investing.com/economic-calendar/cpi-733.

This is the code I created to scrape the table:

`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

class ScrapySoup:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site
    
    def exploit_table(self):
        hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        req = Request(self.site, headers=hdr)
        res = urlopen(req)
        rawpage = res.read().decode("utf-8") 
        page = rawpage.replace('<!-->', '')
        # Use BeautifulSoup to exploit the table
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find("table", {"class": "genTbl openTbl ecHistoryTbl"})
        # Preparazione delle liste per raccogliere i dati
        headers = []
        rows = []
        # Estrazione degli header della tabella
        for header in table.find_all('th'):
            headers.append(header.get_text().strip())
        # Estrazione delle righe della tabella
        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            if len(cells) > 0:
                rows.append([cell.get_text().strip() for cell in cells])
        # Creazione di un DataFrame di pandas
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
        return df

site = 'https://it.investing.com/economic-calendar/cpi-733'
table = ScrapySoup(site).exploit_table()

table`
```

And this works fine.

However, I'd like to retrieve data from 2020. I already tried what is suggested in [how to scrape historical data from investing.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866926/scrapin-historical-data-from-investing-com), but I can't figure it out how to adapt it.

This is the updated version of Andrej Kesely code, including more information in the headers:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://it.investing.com/economic-calendar/more-history"

data = {
    "eventID": "1",
    "event_attr_ID": "733",
    "event_timestamp": "2023-09-13",
    "is_speech": "0",
}

headers = {
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

dates = pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", freq="180D")

all_dfs = []
with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)

    for d in dates:
        data["event_timestamp"] = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
       
        resp = s.post(url, data=data).json()
        
        table = "<table>" + resp["historyRows"] + "</table>"
        df = pd.read_html(StringIO(table))[0]
        df.columns = [
            "Data di rilascio",
            "Ora",
            "Attuale",
            "Previsto",
            "Precedente",
            "xxx",
        ]
        all_dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
final_df["Data di rilascio"] = pd.to_datetime(
    final_df["Data di rilascio"].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0], dayfirst=True
)
final_df = final_df.sort_values(by="Data di rilascio")
print(final_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can get data for year 2020 from this site into pandas DataFrame:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://it.investing.com/economic-calendar/more-history"

data = {
    "eventID": "1",
    "event_attr_ID": "733",
    "event_timestamp": "2023-09-13",
    "is_speech": "0",
}

headers = {
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

dates = pd.date_range("2019-12-31", "2021-01-31", freq="180D")

all_dfs = []
with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)

    for d in dates:
        data["event_timestamp"] = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        resp = s.post(url, data=data).json()

        table = "<table>" + resp["historyRows"] + "</table>"
        df = pd.read_html(StringIO(table))[0]
        df.columns = [
            "Data di rilascio",
            "Ora",
            "Attuale",
            "Previsto",
            "Precedente",
            "xxx",
        ]
        all_dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
final_df["Data di rilascio"] = pd.to_datetime(
    final_df["Data di rilascio"].str.rsplit(n=1).str[0], dayfirst=True
)
final_df = final_df.sort_values(by="Data di rilascio")

print(final_df[final_df["Data di rilascio"].dt.year == 2020])
```

Prints:

```
  Data di rilascio    Ora Attuale Previsto Precedente  xxx
5       2020-01-14  14:30    2,3%     2,3%       2,1%  NaN
4       2020-02-13  14:30    2,5%     2,4%       2,3%  NaN
3       2020-03-11  13:30    2,3%     2,2%       2,5%  NaN
2       2020-04-10  13:30    1,5%     1,6%       2,3%  NaN
1       2020-05-12  13:30    0,3%     0,4%       1,5%  NaN
0       2020-06-10  13:30    0,1%     0,2%       0,3%  NaN
5       2020-07-14  13:30    0,6%     0,6%       0,1%  NaN
4       2020-08-12  13:30    1,0%     0,8%       0,6%  NaN
3       2020-09-11  13:30    1,3%     1,2%       1,0%  NaN
2       2020-10-13  13:30    1,4%     1,4%       1,3%  NaN
1       2020-11-12  14:30    1,2%     1,3%       1,4%  NaN
0       2020-12-10  14:30    1,2%     1,1%       1,2%  NaN
```

Comment: It's still giving me an error, in particular: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

and then:

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @Ricter Make sure you don't get captcha page. Do `print(s.post(url, data=data).text)`

Comment: Moreover, why the event ID you are using is 1? shouldn't be "446379"?

Comment: I'm getting the captcha page, that's the problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Ricter You can try to add more headers to `headers`, such as `User-Agent`

Comment: Tried, but still not working. I edited the initial post to include your code with more headers, so you can check, but still getting the error.
It seems the error is still in:
---> 28         resp = s.post(url, data=data).json()

Comment: @Ricter Running the code you've posted in your question on my computer produces the final dataframe. So it seems your IP is banned...

Comment: Banned? wow
Do you think is a good idea If I write to investing.com to ask for info on that ban?

Comment: @Ricter Better idea is to search for official API to their data or search for a library, e.g. https://github.com/topics/investing-api

Comment: But, why If I run the first code the website is giving me the desired result? If I were banned, it wouldn't give me the results in either case, I suppose